# javascript file directory redirect?

Tags: redirect, path, directory, location, host

I have some javascript that changes the title image based on whatever the host is. My problem is that the redirect path I have "../images/file.jpg" does not work for all the pages that I have. Some of my main pages are in the main folder directory, the others are in a separate folder within the main directory folder called page. All the images used(not located) in page treat page as the main dir.

Does anyone know a way around this, without me having to move the images?

this is my script:

```
if(host == 'mysite.com') {
    document.getElementById("geekhospitalextended").src='../images
/logo/IPD/title/IPD extended.png';
    document.getElementById("urlTitle").src='../images/logo/IPD/title/
IPD extended.png';
    }
```

I have thought about adding some code like:

```
    if(pathname == 'mysite.com/directory1/directory2/images') {
document.getElementById("geekhospitalextended").src='../../../images
/logo/IPD/title/IPD extended.png';
document.getElementById("urlTitle").src='../../../images/logo/IPD/title/
IPD extended.png';
}
```

What could I do if I wanted to set the src path given that certian keywords are included in the path name
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you point to a script that looks for the image in both places, and returns returns the contents of whichever it finds. Or it could return a permanent redirect to that location.

Comment: Yah, in the second part that is kind of what I am trying to accomplish. But that means that I would have to do one for every single file that I have in the page directory.

Comment: Use a rewrite rule that puts the filename in the query string, so you just have one script.

Comment: Actually, I looked up some examples of the rewrite rule and it was way over my head. But I found something easier to understand. Just an FYI and for anyone else who is looking to do the same thing that I was. Here's the link http://www.i3lance.co.uk/2012/09/how-to-check-if-a-url-contains-a-given-string-using-jquery/